# How do I write properly escaped XML in python etree untouched?

Tags: python, xml, elementtree

I'm using python version 2.7.3.

```
test.xml:

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
    <test>The tag &quot;StackOverflow&quot; is good to bring up at parties.</test>
</root>
```

I will change the text in the xml with elementtree. Then I write to the file.
But the the `&lt;` is changed to `<` etc. It will be:

```
test.xml:

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
    <test>The tag "StackOverflow" is good to bring up at parties.</test>
</root>
```

When I write to the file with elementtree.write What I'd like to see:

```
test.xml:

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
    <test>The tag &quot;StackOverflow&quot; is good to bring up at parties.</test>
</root>
```

I'd like to use this text as-is for display within XML, therefore I don't want an XML parser to mess with it.
Is there any way?

I use this code

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

class CommentedTreeBuilder(ET.XMLTreeBuilder):
    def __init__(self):
        ET.XMLTreeBuilder.__init__(self)
        self._parser.CommentHandler = self.handle_comment

    def handle_comment(self, data):
        self._target.start(ET.Comment, {})
        self._target.data(data)
        self._target.end(ET.Comment)


with open('test.xml', 'r') as f:
    tree = ET.parse(f, parser=CommentedTreeBuilder())
    root = tree.getroot()
    test = root.find('test')
    test.text += 'test'
    tree.write('test.xml', encoding="UTF-8", xml_declaration=True)
```

`&gt` doesnt have the problem.  `&quot;` `&#x000A;`  have the problem

Comment: Show the code you've tried.

Comment: I do not get issue with normal `ET.write()` method.

Comment: I  have reedit the question